# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'UUID' objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to update the column in cassendra using python script.

but i am getting error 
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'UUID' objects

```
active = session.execute("select id, status from address where status = 'A'")

for row in activeCampaigns:
    session.execute("update address set status = 'ACTIVE' where id = "+row.id);
```

could someone assist me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`row.id` is most likely a [`UUID`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID) object. You should try either converting it to its string representation before concatenation:

```
session.execute("update ... id = " + str(row.id))
```

or use proper string formatting:

```
session.execute("update ... id = {}".format(row.id))
```

Comment: or `session.execute("update address set status = %s where id = %s", ('ACTIVE', row.id))`